# Add images to div from Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have a *div* `<div runat="server" id="mugshots_container"></div>`. I want to populate it with *images* from Code Behind.

Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((x) => { RefreshMugshots(); }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
}

protected void RefreshMugshots()
{
    DataTable dt = this.ExecSprocReturnDataTable(SPROC_MUGSHOTS_GET);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string identifier = row["identifier"].ToString();

        HtmlImage img = mugshots_container.Controls.OfType<HtmlImage>()
                                                   .SingleOrDefault((x => x.Attributes["identifier"] == identifier));

        if (img != null)
        {
            img.Src = ConvertByteArrayToBase64String(row["image"] as byte[]);
        }
        else
        {
            img = new HtmlImage() { Src = ConvertByteArrayToBase64String(row["image"] as byte[]) };
            img.Attributes.Add("identifier", identifier);

            mugshots_container.Controls.Add(img);
        }
    }
}
```

Code executes fine, the *HtmlImage*'s have been added to *mugshots_container* but I can't see the images on the page. When I open the debugger the *div* is still empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you force page to refresh in your browser? All changes you do to `<div>` happens on the server. Once page is loaded browser is disconnected from the server and you can't push changes to it unless you use push by SignalR or pull by timer on the page.

Comment: you can't do that in a standard way,without having a full postback your images will remain in the server and the client will never see them.

Comment: you should go for an update-panel or a client side solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple possible issues here.  First:

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((x) => { RefreshMugshots(); }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

That is executing on a separate thread.  By the time your thread executes, the original event has completed and the page has been returned to the browser.  No more data will be sent, and the client will have no idea that things have been updated.  Remove the time and just run `RefreshMugshots();` inline with your other page load logic and see if your images display.

The second thing is that most browsers have a limit to the amount of base-64 encoded data that can be stored in an HTML image tag.  Anything exceeding that limit will cause the image not to display.

An alternative (simpler) method that doesn't require dealing with threads and SignalR would be to use client script (eg. `setInterval(...)` to call a handler that returns a URL for the updated image, and then set image source appropriately on your DOM element.

Pseudo-code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var newMugshotUrl = getMugshotUrl(someIdentifier);
        $('#myMugshotImage').attr('src', newMugshotUrl);
    }, 60000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Once the request has finished, it doesn't make any sense to change properties like img.src, as there isn't any client listening in the other side of the wire to re draw your page.

For this you should use some kind of live stream between the client and the server, like SignalAir. http://www.asp.net/signalr